# BaseInterpolator cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, sdk, include

As the title said, **"BaseInterpolator" cannot be resolved to a type** and I couldn't **include it** through

```
import android.view.animation.BaseInterpolator;
```

I've also ***include LinearInterpolator*** ***without any problem*** but this "BaseInterpolator" compiles error today.

```
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
```

The SDK-dependency of this project is:

```
android:minSdkVersion="16"
android:targetSdkVersion="23"
```

Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use:

```
import android.view.animation.Interpolator;
```

[`BaseInterpolator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/BaseInterpolator.html) was added with API 22 for further abstraction. Use the `Interpolator` interface and you are fine.